# Default dialog transition 'none' is still giving me 'pop' transition

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, transition

Is it a bug report or a StackOverflow question... I don't know. I'm working with jQueryMobile on a mobile app and it's doing fine except for the transitions between pages (and dialogs, and between pages and dialogs, and vice versa).

Since between some dialogs all transitions are so bad, I wanted to just switch them off entirely, and jQM has a setting for this:

$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none'.

It does that nicely when testing in Chrome on Windows desktop, but not on an actual Android. There, I still get a 'pop' transition. What's going on?

Edit: setting the data-transition attribute explicitly on each link does work for Android.

Edit 2: Here's the code as requested:

```
//Part 1: The setup
$(window).on("mobileinit",function(){
$.support.cors = true; //cors = cross-origin resource sharing
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;//Finally works now that initializePage is removed

    //Specific for Android's flashing page 
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';

    //Specific for iOS
    $.support.touchOverflow = true;//These two improve page transitions on iOS
    $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
})

//Part 2: The workaround I use to make sure the transition is truly 'none' even on Android.
<a href="#balance" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="none">
```

Comment: Show me your code and tell me what JQM version please

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you include init steps in correct order?

> Because the mobileinit event is triggered immediately upon execution,
>   you'll need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded.
>   Thus, we recommend linking to your JavaScript files in the following
>   order:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I put my mobileinit event handler exactly in between jquery and jquerymobile script.

Comment: I'm starting to think jQM is very forcible when it comes to choosing transition. I know that when the browser does not support CSS transformations, jQM defaults to specific simple transformations. It just seems strange that you can't override those with the 'none' option.

Answer (score 0):

in part two 

you need to remove the "data-transition" attribute from the tag